# Will my Russian developer background be a red flag for European companies?

Tags: job-search, new-job, politics, russia

I am originally from Kazakhstan, I have a Kazakhstan passport and citizenship. But I received my bachelors degree in computer science in Russia, I also worked for 4.5 years for Russian companies, moreover I currently work for a Russian bank, which is sanctioned by US and EU.

Due to current "climate" I am no longer interested in building my future in Russia.
However my background seems unstable and uncertain for me in terms of getting a job in Europe.

I want to know, if European recruiters still consider candidates like me and how can I avoid possible troubles related to it.

Comment: This isn't something anyone can tell really tell you. Different companies will behave differently, and what's true today could be very different in a month or six months.

Comment: @PhilipKendall you are right, on the other hand I believe that some kind of mid-run trend exists. I hope that someone will at least share their experience related to topic of my question

Comment: Why don't you try? I think it is difficult to expect people on this site to have much experience in this situation as it is quite unique. But be prepared to explain in your cover letter your circumstances and motivation.

Comment: Having a passport from Kazakhstan will be a lot better for you than a passport from Russia.

Comment: Depends on what industry, if you want to work for the military or government then it will be near impossible but anything else shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: A company I know of is actively trying to hire Russians as mitigation to the backlash

Comment: My own IT employer (USA-based with branches on all continents) did close its branch in Moscow, but offered a bridge to work in other parts of the world. Most took the easiest path in terms of documents : the branch in the emirates. IT is in demand, and good firms should be interested.

Comment: It's sad that this question even needs to be asked.  I thought everyone in the world (all major political entities anyway) agreed that racism is not OK, and that those who thought racism was ok should be marginalized and deplatformed to the greatest extent possible.  That's what Black Lives Matter was supposed to teach us...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most employers understand that Russians in general aren't responsible for the invasion of Ukraine, and are also suffering from the effects of it. They won't count your nationality against you. My company in Canada has recruited several Russians for remote work in the last two months, and are looking to bring them to Canada.

There are logistical problems with actually working from Russia, including internet access and payment. Relocating to a nearby country such as Georgia may be a good move.

Answer (score 2):

Apply, you have skills that they will be interested in.

While the political picture is difficult, they may still be planning and those skills needed.